# Form input conditioning for styling

Tags: jquery, css

I have this jquery

```
$(function(){
   function validatemin() {
      if (('input[name=amount]').value() <= 2.00) {
          $('#inpamount').css('color', 'red');
      }
      else {
      }
   }
});
```

Which should be triggered onkeyup in the HTML below, changing the input text colour.

```
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="validatemin()">
```

Turning the text red. Any Ideas why it does not work?

Also, how can I change the if so that if `input > 2.00` (as it is now) `OR < VALUE OF ANOTHER ELEMENT`. For example the class of the other element is `otherelement`

Cheers

Comment: you have missed a dollar sign or jQuery in your if statement

Comment: Use your developer console (generally f12 will get you there) for testing. You can either use break points or insert `console.log` statements to see exactly where your code is going and what various variable states are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `validatemin` was not seen because it was within the scope of the `ready` handler. Extract it out
2. To get the value in `jQuery`, use `val()`, not `value()`
3. Before initiating a selector, you need the `jQuery` object or alias `$`

```js
function validatemin() {
  if ($('input[name=amount]').val() <= 2.00) {
    $('#inpamount').css('color', 'red');
  } else {
     $('#inpamount').css('color', '');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inpamount' type="text" name="amount" value="2.00" onkeyup="validatemin()">
```

**Update**

> Also, how can I change the if so that if input > 2.00 (as it is now) OR < VALUE OF ANOTHER ELEMENT. For example the class of the other element is otherelement

Change the `if` condition to

```
if ($('input[name=amount]').val() <= 2.00 || $('.otherelement').val() <= 2.00)
```

Comment: Firstly I would like to thank you for your time and diligence. This works perfect! Two more little points, if someone enters 1.5, which is less than 2, then erases it, and enters again a number bigger than two, what's the easiest way to change it back to black? Secondly, do you know how I could do the second part of the question (seen at the bottom). Thanks for your time :))

Comment: @Semger, see my updated answer. The code snippet solves the first issue. And the **Update** `if` condition should solve the other issue

Comment: Your answers are amazing, and you are a great person! Thanks :-)

Comment: I tried this in the if statement, but if you try run it, you will see the input field briefly goes red and then back to original, even if the input value is bigger than the value of the reffered to element. `if ($('input[name=amount]').val() <= 2.00 || $('input[name=amount]').val() > $(".response2").val()) {`

Comment: @Semger, that seems strange. Can you replicate the problem in  a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I think the issue is the element I am trying to compare the input to is fetched with AJAX so it changes from some loading ext to the value. How can I make the function wait 1 second for example before executing the if statement after onkeyp up

Comment: I dont think waiting is the best approach. Rather, check if its null or not like `if($(elemet).val() <= 2 || ($(otherelement).length && $(otherlement).val() < $(element).v()))`

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uenvzmwj/  . Can you show me how to implement it? For some reason it does not work live on jsfiddle but it does on the site with the same code.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, but, the <span> value is not avaliable for the first second on page load :/

Comment: The span also has a $ sign: in fact right now on the site it looks like this $12.00

Comment: @Semger, right thats why you can check if its loaded or not like `if($(elemet).val() <= 2 || ($(otherelement).length && parseInt($(otherelement)) && $(otherlement).val() < $(element).v()))`